# Mysql + difference in two result sets

Tags: mysql, select, resultset, set-difference

I have a pretty simple MySQL question.  I have two tables, Customer and Orders.  Customer table has fields (id, name) and Order has fields (id,  customerID, and item).
I can find which customer bought product A and customers that bought product B with the following query in MySQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.`id`, c.name, o.`item`, o.qty FROM `customer` as c
INNER JOIN order AS o ON (c.`Id` =  o.`customerID`) 
where o.`item` ="Product A"

Union

SELECT DISTINCT c.`id`, c.name, o.`item`, o.qty FROM `customer` as c
INNER JOIN order AS o ON (c.`Id` =  o.`customerID`) 
where o.`item` ="Product B"
```

How can find the difference and similarity in these two result sets? 
1) I.e. Customers  that bought only  product A but did not by product B
2) I.e. Customers that bought both product A and B

Thank you for your assistance.

D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get the result.